# Using an array to add randomly selected images to a clickable gridview

Tags: java, android, arrays, gridview, random

I want to generate a clickable gridview of images of either variable or 12 length. This I managed fine but I want to pick the images (fruit or whatever) in duplicate pairs (6pairs) at random (from a list) [I also need to connect the matching sounds to the pictures/gridview position for when they are clicked]. Should I add them to an array? I need to connect the matching sounds to the pictures/gridview position for when they are clicked.

Can I populate an array that way? What is the command? e.g. can I add to my array1 this way:

```
array1[n] = arraycontainingimages[randomnumbern];
```

? What are my options or what is the best way? Can I create a null array and then add the images? Which command can add them? Am I better off using the  ArrayList() java command and then add(int index, Object element). I also need to remove the item from the gridview once clicked.

I have some sample code below which may be wrong in any number of ways, my being a beginner. If I am being overly complicated please let me know.

```
public class MyImageAdapterFruit1 extends BaseAdapter {

int Totalfruit = 12; // this means there are 6 pairs of fruit to select
int fruitstilltoadd = Totalfruit;
int ftaddcnt = 1;
int puthere = 1; 
int counttotwo;

private Context mContext;

public MyImageAdapterFruit1(Context c) {
    mContext = c;
}

public int getCount() {
    return filenames.length;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
} 

// Create array to reference images later
public Integer [] displayfruit = {
        R.drawable.blank, 
        R.drawable.fruit1, R.drawable.fruit2, R.drawable.fruit3, 
        R.drawable.fruit4, R.drawable.fruit5, R.drawable.fruit6, 
        R.drawable.fruit7, R.drawable.fruit8, R.drawable.fruit9, 
        R.drawable.fruit10, R.drawable.fruit11, R.drawable.fruit12, 
};

// Create blank array to be populated randomly later - is this right/ok?
private Integer [] filenames;

// CONSIDER USING public void ArrayList (int capacity) {} here instead

//public void whyiseclipseaddingthis()     // Don't know why eclipse is adding this bit--------Fill (filenames) array randomly with 6 images in duplicate

{
while (fruitstilltoadd > 0) { 

//  select Fruittoaddtoarray - the following creates a random number (temprand) between 1 and 12 (if 12 is the total no. of fruit)
//  use this to randomly select fruit to add to the array 
    int restartfruitselection = 0;
    int minr = 1; 
    int maxr = (Totalfruit + 1); 
    Random temprand = new Random();
    int Fruittoaddtoarray = temprand.nextInt(maxr - minr + 1) + minr;
// end "select Fruittoaddtoarray" 

    // Now check if Fruittoaddtoarray already in array named "filenames"
    for (ftaddcnt = 1; ftaddcnt <= Totalfruit; ftaddcnt++) { 
        if (filenames[Fruittoaddtoarray] == filenames[ftaddcnt]) {
            restartfruitselection = 1; break;
            //if already in array then start over selecting new fruit else continue             
        }

    if (restartfruitselection == 0) {
    // new fruit has been selected successfully so lets add it TWICE to random positions
        counttotwo =1; 
        while (counttotwo <= 2) {

            minr = 1; 
            maxr = (Totalfruit + 1); 
            temprand = new Random();
            int Puthere = temprand.nextInt(maxr - minr + 1) + minr;
            // end selection of random Puthere

            //if Puthere location is empty then add fruit to that position in the array ...
            // ...otherwise select a different place to put the fruit and re-test    
            if (filenames[Puthere] == null) {
                filenames[Puthere] = displayfruit[Fruittoaddtoarray]; 
                counttotwo++; 
                fruitstilltoadd--;

            }
        }
    }       
}   
}}

int Fruitleft = 0;        

// create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }

    imageView.setImageResource(filenames[position]);
    return imageView;
}

}
```

Thanks for your help. Any help on any point is welcome.

PS My gameonemainscreen.java file is

```
  GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);
    gridview.setAdapter(new MyImageAdapterFruit1(this));

    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

            SoundManager.playSound(2, 1);     
            Toast.makeText(game1mainscreen.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: Obviously I asked too many questions in one post. I will re-post with improvements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously I asked too many questions in one post. Wont happen again. Short answers are:

1 I used an arraylist instead of an array as you cant modify an array. I swapped out images in my arraylist  as follows:

```
myarraylist.set(position, R.drawable.newimage); //swap for new image
myarraylist.remove(0); //remove first int (image) from array

FruitToChooseFromImages = new ArrayList<Integer>();
FruitToChooseFromImages.add(R.drawable.image1);
FruitToChooseFromImages.add(R.drawable.image2); // etc to add images to the arraylist
```

2 I used:

```
switch (switchused) {
    case R.drawable.fruit0:
            soundtoplay = 0;
            break;
etc.....
```

to match the sounds to the images rather than using two arraylists as I discovered:

```
Collections.shuffle(intarraylistofimages, shufflevalueSeed);
Collections.shuffle(intarraylistofnames, shufflevalueSeed);
```

did not keep the same order for both arrays even when using the same seed, despite articles to the contrary.

3 To change an icon on click I had issues so I just refreshed the entire grid after changing an image:

```
MyGridviewAdapter1.notifyDataChanged();
gridview.invalidateViews();
```